# ionic 3 call api with header token

Tags: angular, ionic3, postman

i have api url and token . In postman the api works fine and showing data . i need to show data in ionic 3 app in console any one know how can i show this ? i try it but its showing error .

api: http://api.igiinsurance.com.pk:8888/insurance_takaful/insurance-api/get_panel_hospitals.php?offset=0&limit=100

token: ee66cf61762eab785b006186dbc8c980

Screenshot of postman :
[image]

i try it with this code but not working .

```
  getDataUsingToken1(token) { 
    const httpOptions = {headers: new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", "token "+token)}; 
     return this.httpClient.get('this.apiurl', httpOptions) 
  }; 

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.getDataUsingToken1(this.token).subscribe(data=>{ 
      console.log(data); 
    },
    err => console.log(err.message)
    );
  }
```

Comment: `'this.apiurl'`? Is this really what is in your code? Shows us the whole class.

Comment: no here is the api i just type it here to short the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try it:**

```
getDataUsingToken1(token) { 
         return this.httpClient.get(this.apiurl,{headers:new HttpHeaders({
                  'token': token
                })) 
      }
```

Comment: give me screen shot

Comment: are you check CORS policy ??

Comment: @UmaizKhan where missing ,

Comment: }))  here i think it saying "," is missing here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191238/discussion-between-umaiz-khan-and-utpaul).

Comment: Thanks bro You saved me <3